# Does the Imperium provide next-of-kin benefits?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Reading [this page](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Astra_Militarum_Awards_and_Honours) on the Warhammer 40k wiki, I noticed the Medallion Crimson is usually issued posthumously, which seemed odd to me.  I had assumed the average fallen guardsmen was forgotten the moment they were buried, just judging by the tone with which their deaths are treated.  If they're forgotten, what would be the point of handing out posthumous awards?  This got me thinking the Imperium must give the awards to their families, which seems uncharacteristically noble considering the rest of the fiction.

So what happens after a guardsman dies?  Does his NCO write a letter home?  Do his relatives get some kind of pension?

Comment: Is it possible it's simply awarded to the merit of his unit?

Comment: In *The Last Chancers*, every one that falls is then scrupulously pardoned, which is described as being as effective in the afterlife.  When you think that the land of the dead is ruled by your own emperor, posthumous awards may even be of value to the dead.

Answer (score 8):

General caveat: customs in the Imperium are not well-standardized; what's true in one region/world/regiment will not necessarily be true in another. However, in at least some cases, the next-of-kin of guardsmen are provided benefits.

As is often the case with the small details of Guard life, this comes out throughout the Gaunt's Ghosts novels, in particular *Salvation's Reach*, where the death benefits given out to next-of-kin are important to two subplots:

- Captain Daur's impending marriage to Elodie, which he considers putting off because of the implication: that is, that he expects to die and wants to marry first so that Elodie will be provided for. It's mentioned that this is common for the rank and file, although they only get a small benefit whereas a captain's is more substantial.
- Captain Meryn's benefits scam. Because the Tanith come from a destroyed planet, and the Verghasts from a destroyed hive, many of their next-of-kin are dead but the Munitorum doesn't have an official record of that fact. Meryn and his cronies then file false claims on behalf of the dead kin and pocket the benefits. As mentioned, it's not much in any one particular case, but they can churn enough to make it worth their while.

There's a discussion (in *The Anarch*, I believe) about dealing with dead guardsmen's equipment. Anything of practical use (extra clothing, weapons, maintenance gear and other kit) is returned to regimental stores to be re-issued; personal effects are sent on to the next-of-kin. In *Necropolis*, mention is made that dog-tags are collected from the fallen and, after being entered in the regiment's record, also sent to the next-of-kin.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, but actually... No**

The Imperium makes it essentially impossible for almost every next-of-kin to actually be able to collect benefits.  Cadence's answer re: the Tanith 1st is spot on.  A spouse (or potentially other next-of-kin like children) can receive a gratuity or pension if they file for one on behalf of their fallen loved one.  Cpt. Meryn and his cronies do this to good effect, via mass-filing so they can turn the pittance-per-casualty into a meaningful amount of money.  That's essentially the Imperial Guard standard.  But it only works for Meryn because he can short-circuit the system.  Because...

It only works if the person Knows To File.  In the Imperial Infantryman's Uplifting Primer (which is an in-universe artifact) there is a section to fill out in case of death.  IF the thing is correctly filled out (to include time/place/manner of death requiring a specificity that's fairly unlikely to be carefully logged in Guard battles.  I direct your attention to the mass-assault Daryn takes part in during Traitor General.) AND if security permits, this document can be sent to the individual's designated next-of-kin.  This poses several problems:
1- You need to know exactly how the person died, exactly when, and exactly where.  "eaten by 'nids on Ambold XII" isn't good enough! Even "killed around noon on the 5th Day of the Assault on Hill 321 by Heretic artillery" isn't specific enough! Not filled out right? Doesn't get sent.
2- Security Permitting means that any Imperial defeat, or even large imperial casualties, are likely going to be considered State Secrets.  Lord Militant Hummel and his men might know the great Land Armada was turned back with heavy losses at Trinity Hive.  The wider Imperium?  Zero Chance. If a regiment takes heavy losses even in victory it might not be enough for the Imperium to send out a hundred thousand "the Imperium Deeply Regrets" notes to a planet.  And again, each form needs to be filled out perfectly.  If everyone who saw you die dies, none of your next-of-kin get notified!
3- Vagaries of the Warp.  I feel like I'm relying heavily on Gaunt's Ghosts, but it took a military band literal years to catch up to its regiment.  There are plenty of examples throughout the fluff of units taking a 3-week journey into the warp only for 100 years to have passed.  Now imagine how much lower priority details of Imperial losses (even unclassified ones) getting back to a regiment's home planet are.  Plus the fact that the ship could make warp and arrive 150 years after the regiment left.  Plus the various filing and sending and tracking down that needs to take place.  Even if by some miracle your "Deeply Regrets" message makes it back to the planet in question, it now has to wend it's way back to a specific person.  Your grandkid might get the message.  Or your grandkid's grandkid.  At which point nobody can claim because grandchildren are not "Next of Kin" as defined by the Munitorum.

So now let's say you've got the "Deeply Regrets" notice.  And it's all filled out and correct and was cleared to be sent to you, by some miracle. (The Imperial Infantryman's Primer seems to indicate it would usually never be sent at all!) AND it made it to you without being lost in the warp/misfiled/came before you died of old age.  Do you know what that form says about "how to claim benefits"?  NOTHING!  It doesn't say a fething thing!

So now you, grieving widow, must navigate the labyrinthine mess of the Departmento Munitorum.  In your copious spare time no doubt.  To figure out if it's even a thing you can do.  Then how to fill everything out on the claims side (presumably at LEAST as meticulous as the "deeply regrets" note) and remember, fething up once is (as usual for Imperial 'handout' type things) grounds for immediate and permanent rejection-of-claim.  Might even be a crime, you know, falsifying documents. And not just any crime, an Arbites-level crime, because it's theft of imperial funds! But let's say you do it, and do it PERFECTLY.  Great.  Now it has to be approved my the Munitorum. Time passes.  Hopefully it doesn't require off-world approval!  Are you dead yet?  No?  Well then congratulations!  You receive, "A few crowns a year" in a world where "a few crowns" can buy you a beer.  Truly the Emperor has smiled upon you!  But in 99.9999% of cases what happens is the "deeply regrets" telegram is left unfilled in the Imperial Infantryman Primer your loved one *hopefully for his/her sake* died carrying.  And you'll never even know they died.

TL/DR: The Imperium has a widow's pension system intentionally set up to be so baroque, labyrinthine, and time-consuming that it's impossible for any but the most lucky/well connected to collect.

**ADDENDUM** This goes for the rank and file and most of the officer class.  A high-ranking officer or suitably heroic junior officer's kid might get into a Schola Progenium (provided both parents are dead) or may be well-positioned enough to actually have a decent chance of getting the gratuity benifit, which is more for officers than it is for troopers.  But even a Lord General's death might be declared a "State secret" with their next-of-kin never getting any sort of official notice which would allow for a pension claim.

Comment: And this is why the Imperium is a special kind of hell, all that damn paperwork :)

Answer (score 3):

Kids of fallen officers or nobles can get into the Schola Progenium:

> The Schola Progenium is one of the many divisions of the Adeptus Ministorum, the state church of the Imperium of Man. It is responsible for the upbringing, education and training of orphans, predominantly those of officers and nobles who have died in the service of the Imperium, often those who once served in the Astra Militarum or Imperial Navy.
>
> From the Fandom [article on the Schola Progenium](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Schola_Progenium)

They therefore don't have to worry for their survival. As for the bereaved of the standard Guardsman, it probably highly depends on the planet they come from.

Bereaved of a member of the Savlar Chem Dogs (a penal legion) will probably not get any compensation for the loss of their kin. On the other hand, I can very well imagine a bereaved of a Mordian Iron Guard to get compensation, simply to keep them loyal to the autarchs and not worried for their family and prepared to lay their life down in the service to their lords.